# Using ng2-charts on angular2 project shows an error with angular2-polyfills

Tags: charts, angular

When I'm trying to use ng2-charts based from http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ and using 5 mins getting started from angular2 I'm getting the following error which guides me no where:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no
longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use 
removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask
```

The project runs fine, the package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15",
    "ng2-charts": "~1.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "typings": "^0.6.8"
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, } from 'angular2/core';
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS}  from 'angular2/http';
import {ConsumerService} from './consumers/url.consumer.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {Hero} from "./Billing"
import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
// webpack html imports
let template = require('./line-chart-demo.html');

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: template,
    providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS, JSONP_PROVIDERS, ConsumerService, CHART_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor (private _consumerService: ConsumerService) {}

    items: Observable<Hero[]>;

    search (term: String) {
    this.items = this._consumerService.getHeroes();
    }


    // lineChart
    private lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
    [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40]
    ];
    private lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
    private lineChartSeries:Array<any> = ['Series A', 'Series B', 'Series C'];
    private lineChartOptions:any = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    multiTooltipTemplate: '<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel %>: <%}%><%= value %>'
    };
    private lineChartColours:Array<any> = [
    { // grey
        fillColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
        fillColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
    },
    { // grey
        fillColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
    ];
    private lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
    private lineChartType:string = 'Line';

    private randomize() {
    let _lineChartData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
        _lineChartData[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].length; j++) {
            _lineChartData[i].push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));

        }
    }
    this.lineChartData = _lineChartData;
    }

    // events
    chartClicked(e:any) {
    console.log(e);
    }

    chartHovered(e:any) {
    console.log(e);
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- http calls -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- charts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
    map: {
      'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

polyfills.js

```
1236=>    Zone.prototype.run = function (fn, applyTo, applyWith) {
        applyWith = applyWith || [];
        var oldZone = global.zone;
        // MAKE THIS ZONE THE CURRENT ZONE
        global.zone = this;
        try {
            this.beforeTask();
            return fn.apply(applyTo, applyWith);
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (this.onError) {
                this.onError(e);
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        finally {
            this.afterTask();
            // REVERT THE CURRENT ZONE BACK TO THE ORIGINAL ZONE
            global.zone = oldZone;
        }
    };
```

applyWith in polyfills breakpoint:

"Unexpected token < Evaluating http://localhost:3000/ng2-charts/ng2-charts Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js"

main.js:

```
System.register(['angular2/platform/browser', './app.component', 'rxjs/Rx'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var browser_1, app_component_1;
    return {
    setters:[
        function (browser_1_1) {
            browser_1 = browser_1_1;
        },
        function (app_component_1_1) {
            app_component_1 = app_component_1_1;
        },
        function (_1) {}],
    execute: function() {
        browser_1.bootstrap(app_component_1.AppComponent);
    }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import 'rxjs/Rx';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: Difficult to tell :-( Could you add some traces or a breakpoint in the `angular2-polyfills.js` file on line 1243? Just to have more hints about the context. For example try to find out the parameters (fn, applyTo, applyWith) of the run function when the error occurs. Perhaps the "pause on exceptions" feature of your debugger could help you... I tried your code but I don't have the error at first sight.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier thanks for looking into it, I just made the debug and got that applyWith had the value "Unexpected token < Evaluating http://localhost:3000/ng2-charts/ng2-charts Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js" so I added main.js and main.ts files into question

Comment: Checkout PrimeNG Charts as an alternative. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/piechart

Answer (score 5):

if you use SystemJS and npm, you should config like this.

```
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-charts': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a map entry in your SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({
  map: {
     'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts'
  },
  packages: {
    …
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems the error is: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js at eval (native) at SystemJSLoader.__exec (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1395:16) at entry.execute (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3521:16) at linkDynamicModule  ..."

Comment: You should add en entry ng2-charts in the package block if you rely on the TypeScript sources of the library

Comment: why map is needed in system.config? we are not adding like that for any other library?

Comment: Map is needed here since one JS file is provided by module and we want that their resolution (using the module name to deduce file name) were handled by SystemJS.