# Adding ng2-charts to Typescript/ Angular 2 project reference path and path to .js file not correct

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

I am a bit confused as to how to add a npm package like ng2-charts to my Angular2 TypeScript project.

By adding :

```
"ng2-charts": "1.0.3"
```

to my package.json file, it gets installed nicely, and when I add 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts' to my typescript page:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterLink, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router'
import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
    selector: 'detailMatch',
    templateUrl: './app/components/match/detail.html',
    directives: [RouterLink, CHART_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

It also works perfectly. The name CHART_DIRECTIVE is found automatically in Visual Studio when I type the first letter etc, but when I try to load the page I get:

```
http://localhost:5000/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js 404 (Not Found)
```

This is because I don't have ng2-charts in that location:

It is stored in "lib\js\ng2-charts\ng2-charts.js"
Like all my other js files for angular, http, bootstrap, router, Rx etc.

So how can I tell angular that the location of the .js files is in:

```
 http://localhost:5000/lib/js/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js
```

Comment: somebody already answered my question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657181/using-ng2-charts-on-angular2-project-shows-an-error-with-angular2-polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657181/using-ng2-charts-on-angular2-project-shows-an-error-with-angular2-polyfills)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using any module loader. Add the ng2-charts.js file to the script references after angular2 library and see if it works

`<script src="/lib/js/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js"></script>`